# Dataclass Optional Field that is Inferred if Missing

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing, python-dataclasses, python-3.10

I want my dataclass to have a field that can either be provided manually, or if it isn't, it is inferred at initialization from the other fields. MWE:

```py
from collections.abc import Sized
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional


@dataclass
class Foo:
    data: Sized
    index: Optional[list[int]] = None

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.index is None:
            self.index = list(range(len(self.data)))

reveal_type(Foo.index)           # Union[None, list[int]]
reveal_type(Foo([1,2,3]).index)  # Union[None, list[int]]
```

How can this be implemented in a way such that:

1. It complies with `mypy` type checking
2. `index` is guaranteed to be of type `list[int]`

I considered using `default_factory(list)`, however, then how does one distinguish the User passing `index=[]` from the sentinel value? Is there a proper solution besides doing

```py
index: list[int] = None  # type: ignore[assignment]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NotImplemented`

```py
from collections.abc import Sized
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Foo:
    data: Sized
    index: list[int] = NotImplemented

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.index is NotImplemented:
            self.index = list(range(len(self.data)))
```

Comment: This is nice and concise. But I could not find any information about why it is that `mypy` considers this safe. I know that `NotImplemented` is a singleton just like `None` and that `mypy` regards it as safe, when it is _returned_ from a typed function. But in this case you are actively assigning it to a variable typed something else (not a union with `NotImplementedType`). Could you elaborate, why this should be valid (as opposed to the `None` case)? Looking at  [this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/363), it might not be treated this way for long, right?

Comment: It seems that it does work because `NotImplemented` is a [subtype of Any](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/cf9bdc2d9861cb61e76b512988d19afe232a958f/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L1189). It's [mentioned in **pyright**](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/3171) as well.

Comment: Interesting. But if that is the case, it makes even less sense to allow it to be used this way, no? Either way, so long as it works.

Comment: Please note that this does not change anything in fact: it just obscures your "type-ignore" comment. It is funny feature, which can make others try to wrap their heads around it, while `# type: ignore` is pretty obvious here ("Assigning None, because we have some processing in `__post_init__`, so it never remains None"). You could assign any other thing with mypy-type `Any`, including some class imported from untyped package - but is it a good solution? `NotImplemented` is a builtin constant with a very specific meaning: it's return of binary methods, if they are called with unknown arg type.

Comment: (Everything above is just to say "there is **nothing wrong** with ignore comment, if it is used wisely!" Really, if typing forces you to develop some difficult to understand or complex constructs, and troubles can be resolved via ignore comment - use it, it's a great feature)

Answer (score 2):

You can have the `default_factory` return a list with a sentinel object as its only element. You just need to make sure that the sentinel is an instance of `int`, otherwise `mypy` will complain. Luckily we have *identity* comparisons to ensure that the check in `__post_init__` is always correct.

```py
from collections.abc import Sized
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Foo:
    class _IdxSentinel(int):
        pass
    _idx_sentinel = _IdxSentinel()

    @staticmethod
    def _idx_sentinel_factory() -> list[int]:
        return [Foo._idx_sentinel]

    data: Sized
    index: list[int] = field(default_factory=_idx_sentinel_factory)

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        if len(self.index) == 1 and self.index[0] is self.__class__._idx_sentinel:
            self.index = list(range(len(self.data)))
```

I put the entire factory and sentinel logic *inside* of `Foo`, but if you don't like that, you can also factor it out:

```py
from collections.abc import Sized
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

class _IdxSentinel(int):
    pass

_idx_sentinel = _IdxSentinel()

def _idx_sentinel_factory() -> list[int]:
    return [_idx_sentinel]

@dataclass
class Foo:
    data: Sized
    index: list[int] = field(default_factory=_idx_sentinel_factory)

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        if len(self.index) == 1 and self.index[0] is _idx_sentinel:
            self.index = list(range(len(self.data)))
```

---

**EDIT**: Inspired by the comment from @SUTerliakov, here is slightly less verbose version that still satisfies type checkers and linters using a `lambda`-expression instead of a named function:

```py
from collections.abc import Sized
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class Foo:
    class _IdxSentinel(int):
        pass
    _idx_sentinel = _IdxSentinel()

    data: Sized
    index: list[int] = field(default_factory=lambda: [Foo._idx_sentinel])

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        if len(self.index) == 1 and self.index[0] is self.__class__._idx_sentinel:
            self.index = list(range(len(self.data)))
```

Comment: I guess this is the more principled solution compared to Pawel's, but it's just so much extra stuff.

Comment: @Hyperplane I agree. So long as type checkers are fine with his approach, I would use that too.

Comment: Great solution! Note that you don't really need `_idx_sentinel_factory` to be `staticmethod` in first case - without decorator it will still work during class creation, but become unavailable later (any calls from outside of class body will raise), which may be desired behaviour. And `class _IdxSentinel` can be simplified to `type` call, although it's purely matter of preference.

Comment: @SUTerliakov I appreciate the comment and I wish we could reduce the verbosity of the sentinel factory, but both your suggestions will lead to problems with type checkers and/or linters. Dynamic `type` creation is obviously still opaque to `mypy` and others, so it will complain that we don't have an `int` subtype (even if we do). As for the "temporary" namespace function, that may be statically correct, but leads to complaints by both `mypy` and PyCharm, and frankly I have to agree that the style would be fairly questionable. Maybe a `lambda`-expression would work instead.

Comment: * meant to say _"that may be **syntactically** correct..."_

Comment: Ough, sorry, I forgot that `mypy` decided to deny functions declared in class scope not as methods, you're right. `type` call will pass type checker, but for other reason: it is `Any` for `mypy`, so essentially reduces to another answer to this question with "just use something `Any`-ish". Some other type checkers can handle simple `type` calls, AFAIC. So this seems to be really minimal...

Comment: @SUTerliakov Yeah, but the more I deal with this stuff, the more I am on the side of `mypy` regarding `type`. Because what do you define as "simple", right? Where do you draw the line? _Is_ there even a reasonable way to draw the line? Theoretically the type creation can become extremely complex, so it has to be drawn somewhere. It always comes down to my new mantra in recent weeks: _"Static type checkers don't execute your code, they just read it."_ Treating dynamic type creation as opaque seems to be the most consistent approach. But this is a different discussion. :)